# Display list of default ringtones in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtone

I just want to show the list of default ringtones to allow the user select one to set as ringtone for a new notification. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

- (IBAction) AddMusicOrShowMusic: (id) sender
{
    MPMediaPickerController *picker =
    [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = NO;
    picker.prompt                       = NSLocalizedString (@"Add songs to play", "Prompt in media item picker");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated: YES];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [picker release];
}

- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    item = [[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0];
       NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    NSLog(@"url : %@",url);
}
- (void) mediaPickerDidCancel: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: This will show us only all music on a device, not ringtones.

Answer (score 4):

Use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`

```
void AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (
   SystemSoundID inSystemSoundID
);
```

the list of systemSoundID are :

```
1000    new-mail.caf    new-mail.caf    MailReceived    
1001    mail-sent.caf   mail-sent.caf   MailSent    
1002    Voicemail.caf   Voicemail.caf   VoicemailReceived   
1003    ReceivedMessage.caf ReceivedMessage.caf SMSReceived 
1004    SentMessage.caf SentMessage.caf SMSSent 
1005    alarm.caf   sq_alarm.caf    CalendarAlert   
1006    low_power.caf   low_power.caf   LowPower    
1007    sms-received1.caf   sms-received1.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   
1008    sms-received2.caf   sms-received2.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   
1009    sms-received3.caf   sms-received3.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   
1010    sms-received4.caf   sms-received4.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   
1011    -   -   SMSReceived_Vibrate 
1012    sms-received1.caf   sms-received1.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   
1013    sms-received5.caf   sms-received5.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   
1014    sms-received6.caf   sms-received6.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   
1015    Voicemail.caf   Voicemail.caf   -   Available since 2.1
1016    tweet_sent.caf  tweet_sent.caf  SMSSent Available since 5.0
1020    Anticipate.caf  Anticipate.caf  SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1021    Bloom.caf   Bloom.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1022    Calypso.caf Calypso.caf SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1023    Choo_Choo.caf   Choo_Choo.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1024    Descent.caf Descent.caf SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1025    Fanfare.caf Fanfare.caf SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1026    Ladder.caf  Ladder.caf  SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1027    Minuet.caf  Minuet.caf  SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1028    News_Flash.caf  News_Flash.caf  SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1029    Noir.caf    Noir.caf    SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1030    Sherwood_Forest.caf Sherwood_Forest.caf SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1031    Spell.caf   Spell.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1032    Suspense.caf    Suspense.caf    SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1033    Telegraph.caf   Telegraph.caf   SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1034    Tiptoes.caf Tiptoes.caf SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1035    Typewriters.caf Typewriters.caf SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1036    Update.caf  Update.caf  SMSReceived_Alert   Available since 4.2
1050    ussd.caf    ussd.caf    USSDAlert   
1051    SIMToolkitCallDropped.caf   SIMToolkitCallDropped.caf   SIMToolkitTone  
1052    SIMToolkitGeneralBeep.caf   SIMToolkitGeneralBeep.caf   SIMToolkitTone  
1053    SIMToolkitNegativeACK.caf   SIMToolkitNegativeACK.caf   SIMToolkitTone  
1054    SIMToolkitPositiveACK.caf   SIMToolkitPositiveACK.caf   SIMToolkitTone  
1055    SIMToolkitSMS.caf   SIMToolkitSMS.caf   SIMToolkitTone  
1057    Tink.caf    Tink.caf    PINKeyPressed   
1070    ct-busy.caf ct-busy.caf AudioToneBusy   There was no category for this sound before 4.0.
1071    ct-congestion.caf   ct-congestion.caf   AudioToneCongestion There was no category for this sound before 4.0.
1072    ct-path-ack.caf ct-path-ack.caf AudioTonePathAcknowledge    There was no category for this sound before 4.0.
1073    ct-error.caf    ct-error.caf    AudioToneError  There was no category for this sound before 4.0.
1074    ct-call-waiting.caf ct-call-waiting.caf AudioToneCallWaiting    There was no category for this sound before 4.0.
1075    ct-keytone2.caf ct-keytone2.caf AudioToneKey2   There was no category for this sound before 4.0.
1100    lock.caf    sq_lock.caf ScreenLocked    
1101    unlock.caf  sq_lock.caf ScreenUnlocked  
1102    -   -   FailedUnlock    
1103    Tink.caf    sq_tock.caf KeyPressed  
1104    Tock.caf    sq_tock.caf KeyPressed  
1105    Tock.caf    sq_tock.caf KeyPressed  
1106    beep-beep.caf   sq_beep-beep.caf    ConnectedToPower    
1107    RingerChanged.caf   RingerChanged.caf   RingerSwitchIndication  
1108    photoShutter.caf    photoShutter.caf    CameraShutter   
1109    shake.caf   shake.caf   ShakeToShuffle  Available since 3.0
1110    jbl_begin.caf   jbl_begin.caf   JBL_Begin   Available since 3.0
1111    jbl_confirm.caf jbl_confirm.caf JBL_Confirm Available since 3.0
1112    jbl_cancel.caf  jbl_cancel.caf  JBL_Cancel  Available since 3.0
1113    begin_record.caf    begin_record.caf    BeginRecording  Available since 3.0
1114    end_record.caf  end_record.caf  EndRecording    Available since 3.0
1115    jbl_ambiguous.caf   jbl_ambiguous.caf   JBL_Ambiguous   Available since 3.0
1116    jbl_no_match.caf    jbl_no_match.caf    JBL_NoMatch Available since 3.0
1117    begin_video_record.caf  begin_video_record.caf  BeginVideoRecording Available since 3.0
1118    end_video_record.caf    end_video_record.caf    EndVideoRecording   Available since 3.0
1150    vc~invitation-accepted.caf  vc~invitation-accepted.caf  VCInvitationAccepted    Available since 4.0
1151    vc~ringing.caf  vc~ringing.caf  VCRinging   Available since 4.0
1152    vc~ended.caf    vc~ended.caf    VCEnded Available since 4.0
1153    ct-call-waiting.caf ct-call-waiting.caf VCCallWaiting   Available since 4.1
1154    vc~ringing.caf  vc~ringing.caf  VCCallUpgrade   Available since 4.1
1200    dtmf-0.caf  dtmf-0.caf  TouchTone   
1201    dtmf-1.caf  dtmf-1.caf  TouchTone   
1202    dtmf-2.caf  dtmf-2.caf  TouchTone   
1203    dtmf-3.caf  dtmf-3.caf  TouchTone   
1204    dtmf-4.caf  dtmf-4.caf  TouchTone   
1205    dtmf-5.caf  dtmf-5.caf  TouchTone   
1206    dtmf-6.caf  dtmf-6.caf  TouchTone   
1207    dtmf-7.caf  dtmf-7.caf  TouchTone   
1208    dtmf-8.caf  dtmf-8.caf  TouchTone   
1209    dtmf-9.caf  dtmf-9.caf  TouchTone   
1210    dtmf-star.caf   dtmf-star.caf   TouchTone   
1211    dtmf-pound.caf  dtmf-pound.caf  TouchTone   
1254    long_low_short_high.caf long_low_short_high.caf Headset_StartCall   
1255    short_double_high.caf   short_double_high.caf   Headset_Redial  
1256    short_low_high.caf  short_low_high.caf  Headset_AnswerCall  
1257    short_double_low.caf    short_double_low.caf    Headset_EndCall 
1258    short_double_low.caf    short_double_low.caf    Headset_CallWaitingActions  
1259    middle_9_short_double_low.caf   middle_9_short_double_low.caf   Headset_TransitionEnd   
1300    Voicemail.caf   Voicemail.caf   SystemSoundPreview  
1301    ReceivedMessage.caf ReceivedMessage.caf SystemSoundPreview  
1302    new-mail.caf    new-mail.caf    SystemSoundPreview  
1303    mail-sent.caf   mail-sent.caf   SystemSoundPreview  
1304    alarm.caf   sq_alarm.caf    SystemSoundPreview  
1305    lock.caf    sq_lock.caf SystemSoundPreview  
1306    Tock.caf    sq_tock.caf KeyPressClickPreview    The category was SystemSoundPreview before 3.2.
1307    sms-received1.caf   sms-received1.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   
1308    sms-received2.caf   sms-received2.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   
1309    sms-received3.caf   sms-received3.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   
1310    sms-received4.caf   sms-received4.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   
1311    -   -   SMSReceived_Vibrate 
1312    sms-received1.caf   sms-received1.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   
1313    sms-received5.caf   sms-received5.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   
1314    sms-received6.caf   sms-received6.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   
1315    Voicemail.caf   Voicemail.caf   SystemSoundPreview  Available since 2.1
1320    Anticipate.caf  Anticipate.caf  SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1321    Bloom.caf   Bloom.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1322    Calypso.caf Calypso.caf SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1323    Choo_Choo.caf   Choo_Choo.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1324    Descent.caf Descent.caf SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1325    Fanfare.caf Fanfare.caf SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1326    Ladder.caf  Ladder.caf  SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1327    Minuet.caf  Minuet.caf  SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1328    News_Flash.caf  News_Flash.caf  SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1329    Noir.caf    Noir.caf    SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1330    Sherwood_Forest.caf Sherwood_Forest.caf SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1331    Spell.caf   Spell.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1332    Suspense.caf    Suspense.caf    SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1333    Telegraph.caf   Telegraph.caf   SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1334    Tiptoes.caf Tiptoes.caf SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1335    Typewriters.caf Typewriters.caf SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1336    Update.caf  Update.caf  SMSReceived_Selection   Available since 4.2
1350    -   -   RingerVibeChanged   
1351    -   -   SilentVibeChanged   
4095    -   -   Vibrate There was no category for this sound before 2.2.
```