# Access apple's iOS ringtones and display them

Tags: ios, iphone, ringtone

I'm working on an app which has a messaging system in it. I want to the user to setup their own ringtone from the ones provided by Apple, or use something in the iPod library.

All of the answers am finding are saying Apple doesn't allow us to access these ringtones, but there are plenty of apps, including  Whatsapp, which shows you a list for Apple's ringtones for the user to set a text message tone.

How can I get these ringtones so I can add them to a `UITableView`? I understand that they are not available in the simulator, but they are in my iPhone, so I could always test that feature on a device.

Comment: but no body answered the question, how did whatsapp and  similar apps used apple ringtones?? from where did they get  them?

Comment: Answers at both [Access built in iOS alarm clock sound in my app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9524032) and [Display list of default ringtones in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14832055) say that you need to include the files in your app bundle. For where to get them, it's all but certain that they're available on the web.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the list of installed ringtones. Whatsapp is bundling the tones in their resource file, then listing the tones that are available in their bundle,

Comment: does Apple allow us to download their ringtones then? if so, where can i download them? Thanks

Comment: @hsn I hope you can get it by simple googling..:)

Comment: so does that mean there is no copyright regarding these ringtones??

Comment: @hsn Hopefully not. if so, then Whatsapp should also get rejected.