# How to assign device alert tones as notitfication sound in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to get only Alert tones of device (not all the device sounds) and select one of them as my app notification.
I've gone through Apple documentation which states that we cannot use System Sounds for our app.But, in WhatsApp you can see this feature.
Please help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You Not put Alert Notification sound means Its default Take System(iPhone or iPad) Message Tone.

You can't get List of Tones from iPhone.Apple not allowed this. WhatsApp may be used for copy the tones and add their resource file.

Reference:
[Access apple's iOS ringtones and display them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065933/access-apples-ios-ringtones-and-display-them)

Comment: I want to get the list of default alert tones available in iPhone and select one of them as my notification sound.

Comment: You can't get it. Apple not allowed

Answer (score 0):

The `aps` dictionary contains a property that specify a sound to play:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got a push.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff" //here
    }
}
```

You have to embed the sound file in your app, if you like the systems sounds, then try to make your own.

[**Documentation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

> The name of a sound file in the application bundle. The sound in this
>   file is played as an alert. If the sound file doesn’t exist or default
>   is specified as the value, the default alert sound is played. The
>   audio must be in one of the audio data formats that are compatible
>   with system sounds; see “Preparing Custom Alert Sounds” for details.